# Warning: Illegal string offset 'itemID'

Tags: magento2, php-7

this is the error I get with my Magento 2 module, in my logs:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'itemID' in
>   /a/www/vhosts/domain.com/mage2.domain.com/deploy003/app/code/Maurisource/Lightspeed/Helper/Catalog/Product/Configurable.php
>   on line 68

This is line:68 it's referring to:

```
foreach ($rawData['Items']['Item'] as $item) {
    $simpleProductLightspeedId[] = $item['itemID'];
}
```

This is the output of debug.log

```
$this->_logger->debug(json_encode($rawData['Items']['Item']));
```

> [2017-11-22 21:43:36] main.DEBUG:
>   [{"itemID":"14","systemSku":"210000000020","defaultCost":"0","avgCost":"0","discountable":"true","tax":"true","archived":"false","itemType":"default","serialized":"false","description":"manesh-matrix-color
>   a b
>   c","modelYear":"0","upc":"","ean":"","customSku":"","manufacturerSku":"","createTime":"2016-05-02T18:33:46+00:00","timeStamp":"2016-06-02T19:22:26+00:00","publishToEcom":"false","categoryID":"2","taxClassID":"1","departmentID":"0","itemMatrixID":"3","itemAttributesID":"3","manufacturerID":"5","noteID":"16","seasonID":"0","defaultVendorID":"0","itemECommerceID":"0","Prices":{"ItemPrice":[{"amount":"788","useTypeID":"1","useType":"Default"},{"amount":"788","useTypeID":"2","useType":"MSRP"},{"amount":"788","useTypeID":"3","useType":"Online"}]}},

I think this error suggests that $rawData['Items']['Item'] is not an array. But I'm not sure what's wrong here, any hints?

Comment: `print_r($rawData['Items']['Item'])`.. print your object and see what you are getting in there

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal Here's what's printed out

Comment: the things which you access are not array, So it show this error.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya - Correct. But any hints on how to access 'itemID' ? Since Magento brackets are considered as array [ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before the foreach loop I used the following code to fix the issue:

```
if(!isset($rawData['Items']['Item'][0]))
    $rawData['Items']['Item'][] = $rawData['Items']['Item'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
$jsonarray = json_decode(json_encode($rawData['Items']['Item'])); 
foreach ($jsonarray as $item) 
{
    $simpleProductLightspeedId[] = $item['itemID'];
}
```

Comment: Hi this doens't work. I still get the same error as above

Comment: Have you $jsonarray log this array? what it return?

Answer (score 0):

I traced the code

```
public function getOptionText($value)
{
    $options = $this->getAllOptions();
    // Fixed for tax_class_id and custom_design
    if (sizeof($options) > 0) {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if (isset($option['value']) && $option['value'] == $value) {
                return isset($option['label']) ? $option['label'] : $option['value'];
            }
        }
    }
    // End
    if (isset($options[$value])) {
        return $options[$value];
    }
    return false;
}
```

on AbstractSource.php

the proplem is array variable passed to the isset function should be referecne variable.

ignore warning on php ini or pass the parameter to the new variable.